Outlook (Web) Add-in for deleted items
Is there a way to make my Outlook Web Add-in available for every mail item, like also for deleted items?
The Outlook VSTO Add-in that was used to upload mails to our internal ERP system was due for an update, which included adding new features. This add-in was made more than 10 years ago, and we no longer have the source code available, so I decided to create a new Outlook Add-in. Given that COM and VSTO Add-ins will no longer be supported in the new Outlook, and some of the requested features would be easier done using web technologies, I made the new Outlook Add-in using the new Web API instead. Eventually I got things working (outside the preview version, getting a .eml file requires quite a bit of effort), but I am only able to get my new Outlook Add-in to show up at the Inbox and Sent Items.
The previous VSTO plugin worked everywhere, to which my users are accustomed and they expect for example to be able to upload deleted items.
Is this possible for Web Add-ins too? Right now my manifest.xml uses <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">, but that seems to be the only working extension point type. The other types listed do not seem applicable for my use case. Am I overlooking something?
